# Fit a curve to data with positive and negative peaks

Tags: curve-fitting

I have some data from a finite element electromagnetic simulation, and I'd like to fit a curve to it (to allow me to scale the data without numerical artefacts). It goes to zero at plus/minus infinity and has two peaks, one positive and one negative.

[image: double peak distribution]

Original data here: http://pastebin.com/pjKTym8j

I've tried fitting a pair of Gaussians but it doesn't seem a very good fit. Any ideas?

Edit: the 'lumpiness' of it is not important to me, and probably not physical. I'm only interested in the (asymmetric) peaks at z=0 and z=18.

Comment: A higher degree polynomial? E.g. 4 degrees.

Comment: No, that doesn't help. It's a very bad fit, and besides doesn't have the property of going to zero at ±∞.

Comment: E.g. $a*(x+b)*e^{-c*(x-d)^2}$ might nearly do the job?! The going to zero at $\pm \infty$ can be achieved by e.g. a $e^{-c*(x-d)^2}$ function (or another positive function going to zero as $|x|$ goes to infinity and the function being positive for larger values and negative for lower values by a $(x+b)$ factor (or something similar that also goes to infinity slower than the other factor). Perhaps it needs another function multiplied on to get the behaviour in the $(-40, 40)$ interval right. Or is there a physical law that has the particular form?

Comment: That's the type of thing I'm looking for. Maybe it should be something other than a Gaussian to get the central sharpness and long tail.

Comment: Yes, using the Cauchy distribution seems to give a decent fit: $$a(x+b)\frac{1}{π c}\frac{c^2}{(x-d)^2+c^2}$$

Comment: Since your purpose is to remove "numerical artefacts," why try to fit a curve at all?  There are many methods to smooth data. Choosing a good one requires some assumptions about the nature of those artefacts as well as a clear idea of how the smoothed curve will be used. For instance, are you interested in estimating the peak heights?  Their positions?  The area under the curve?  The final decay rate?  *Etc.*

Comment: It's not smoothing that I'm trying to do; it's finding a good parametrisation of this curve given the things I know about it. This data represents what happens to a magnetic field when part of the model is changed by a small amount. To represent a large number of those changes, I need a simple function that represents a small change.